# Convert cookies as dict to cookies as string for HTTP request

Tags: python

I have the following cookie, stored as a dict:

```
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
{'nflx-rgn': '"ue1|1433799654706|uw2:2"', 'SecureNetflixId': 'v%3D2%26mac%3DAQEAEQABABTh6lNR0cbOgGRD7DT7CChBIhA83qsfV_k.%26dt%3D1433799654968', 'memclid': '9a55d2c6-4d85-44bb-8338-0b1a180a7c44', 'NetflixId': 'v%3D2%26ct%3DBQAOAAEBEFP07qwktIitvHYO-Xn6gU2BYKymzutSFtIyfD_zEWVo4yMjbjJ4LgPmtZhjgE5lRWg5OTP8C1N2zNbTc8VsdzUS3OaLnsGsV4AkXZzkewt0X0WcMwSYVl3-pX8Rs0jH2PCXixD8K2oARmtQIrWCvv35EUOpGCb3v-tExqpZaN_6FBfTrF68FXcR4kDGAjXYooBWKnCv1aS1VVscso_GRg6HH7--qOsjW7WoPkxyRAAqt0GmeD8tY5aQHMbD779s7oiAr7YArEmUC_3Hdej0huyGo0Iq-_IlY_jGZhyupIO0ZIpznvGB2teF8YeaiSh2LlQ4RIlUOo3hO5n9lmlmBnRXAYGYbJ_64HiwTfsw3jRWkgAJWnnxSHo9sGLJibspLCQ3RzdA-JwxSPYoBh-HkhnAxxPveWmPbH_1JtXR9rvhfnenIhDgzu_nCUH7i-sxg4bnKhGjpVzH1Y8x9wSNE2-xWdax912FBEzQWyT5I2HxnQQ.%26bt%3Dusr%26ch%3DAQEAEAABABRxRbrqqSNQFSxPcuqeaLCNvVMfYe40K6A.%26mac%3DAQEAEAABABTQs51fmHZefZn26dZQFm9ZDMjlNgmXis8.', 'tlr': 'US|1433799655947'}
```

How would I then add that to my requests header so it would be valid. For example:

```
headers = {
        "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6",
        "Connection" : "keep-alive",
        "Cookies": ???
}
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I would prefer to do this over adding in the `cookies` argument to requests.

Comment: whats wrong with creating a cookie in the request?

Comment: ``headers["Cookie"] = cookies[cookies.keys()[0]]``?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this:

```
cookie_string = "; ".join([str(x)+"="+str(y) for x,y in cookies.items()])
headers = {
        "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6",
        "Connection" : "keep-alive",
        "Cookies": cookie_string
}
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: The answer would even be better if the reverse was also included (how to get the cookie string back to a dict).

Comment: In my case, use `"Cookie"` instead of `"Cookies"` in the headers.

Comment: Surely this is missing url encoding for the cookies, no? What if the cookie value contains special characters?

Comment: @ResignedJune2023 I just looked into this, and it seems that special characters in cookies are already URL-encoded by the server when sent to the client. Requests then stores them as-is, in their escaped form, so no additional escaping is needed when outputting them.